# Finding the limit of $f(x)$ defined differently for rationals and irrationals as $x\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
2x, & x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
4-2x, & x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

I am trying to determine if $$\lim_{x\to 1/2}f(x) = 1$$

I attempted a solution but I am not sure if it is correct or not.
Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $x_n \rightarrow 1/2$. Then given $\varepsilon$ there exists $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ we have |$x_n -\frac{1}{2}|<\varepsilon$.

Now consider 2 cases:

1. When $x_n$ is rational, we have $|f(x_n)-1| = |2x_n -1| = 2|x_n - \tfrac12|<2\varepsilon$.
2. When $x_n$ is irrational we have $|f(x_n) - 3| = |4-2x_n-3| = |2x_n -1| <2\varepsilon$.

Thus $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1/2}f(x) \neq 1$$

Is this argument ok?

Comment: looks good to me. except that as gt6989b pointed out, you only need the irrational sequence that approaches 1/2, the rational sequence is not needed

Answer (score 4):

Take two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \frac12$$

And for large $n$,
$$a_n\in\mathbb Q,\qquad b_n\in\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$$

For example they may be defined as:
$$a_n=\frac12+\frac1n,\qquad b_n=\frac12+\frac{\pi}{n}$$

Then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} (2a_n)=1$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(b_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} (4-2b_n)=3$$

So the function doesn't have limit at $1/2$ at all.

Answer (score 0):

To show it's not one, you really only need the irrational sequence, and you must show you can be at least a certain amount away from 1...

Comment: I know the formal epsilon-delta definition of a limit, but I was using a different approach here

Comment: @dable to show $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) \ne b$$ you would still need to show that it is possible to get arbitrarily close to $a$ while not getting closer to $b$. Your proof fails to explicitly do that.

Comment: I am using the fact that if for all sequences of elements in the domain that converge to $1/2$ we have that $f(x_n$) converges to 1, then the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 1/2$ is also 1.

Comment: @dable You need the contrapositive of that, which needs to be stated explicitly.

Comment: Sorry I meant I am using the contrapositive